# internet explorer ajax request not authenticated

Tags: ajax, facebook, internet-explorer, authentication, iframe

My application workflow is like this: users are authenticated, they start a game and after some time I make an ajax request to get some data, but this request is also authenticated.

The problem is that when first ajax request is made, internet explorer sees the user as unauthenticated and it forces redirect, and everything works fine.

This problem occurs only on internet explorer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your application runs in an IFRAME then you should set P3P headers in order to enable cookies.

You should send a special HTTP header in your first response:

```
P3P: CP="ALL DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND COM NAV"
```

This should solve the problem for IE, but you'll probably hit the same problem in Chrome and Safari. It only appears when user visits your app for the first time. You can emulate it by clearing all the personal information from your browser using browser cleanup feature.

I resolved this problem by storing initial signed_request attribute to a Javascript variable and sending it in all AJAX request as an additional HTTP header (it's possible if you use jQuery). Also, I added the same attribute to all links and forms.

Sample code:

```
var signed_request = '...'; // My signed request goes here

...

function signedUrl(url){
  var url_parts = url.split('#', 2);

  var new_url = url_parts[0] + (url_parts[0].indexOf('?') == -1 ? '?' : '&') + 'stored_signed_request=' + signed_request;

  if(url_parts.length == 2) {
    new_url = new_url + '#' + url_parts[1];
  }

  return new_url;
}

...

  if(document.cookie.indexOf('fbsr_') == -1){
    $('a').live('click', function(){
      var href = $(this).attr('href') || '';

      if(href !== ''){
        $(this).attr('href', signedUrl(href));
      }
    });

    $('form').live('submit', function(){
      $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="stored_signed_request" value="' + signed_request + '">');
    });

    $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend : function(request){
        request.setRequestHeader('signed-request', signed_request);
      }
    });
  }
```